# how do you check if list exists in R

Tags: r

I am reading html table with rvest package like this:

this is the html file I am trying to read. In this case q[[2]] exists but sometimes, q[[2]] does not exists:

```
<html> <head> <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="60, cecutil2.cgi?V1P1"/> <style type="text/css"> th,td {font-size:12px; height:14px} table {border-collapse:collapse;} </style> </head> <body> <table width="100%" cols="6" border="2px">
<tr><td style="width:50px; text-align:center"><a href="zview.html" target="_blank" title="v1p1.mf.example.com:1024 (10.175.128.62)">V1P1</a></td><th width="55px">15/06/22</th><th width="40px">12:21</th>
<th width="65px">3B0F97-0</th><th style="width:50px">19.11%</th> <td align="left"><img height="100%" src="grnline.gif" width="19.10954%"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3"></td>
<th width="65px">3B0F97-1</th><th style="width:50px">20.69%</th> <td align="left"><img height="100%" src="grnline.gif" width="20.68669%"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3"></td>
<th width="65px">3B0F97-2</th><th style="width:50px">22.14%</th> <td align="left"><img height="100%" src="grnline.gif" width="22.13768%"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3"></td>
<th width="65px">3B0F97-3</th><th style="width:50px">35.25%</th> <td align="left"><img height="100%" src="grnline.gif" width="35.24557%"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3"></td>
<th width="65px">3B0F97-4</th><th style="width:50px">38.04%</th> <td align="left"><img height="100%" src="grnline.gif" width="38.03592%"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3"></td>
<th width="65px">3B0F97-5</th><th style="width:50px">23.73%</th> <td align="left"><img height="100%" src="grnline.gif" width="23.73468%"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3"></td>
<th width="65px"> Total </th><th style="width:50px">659.55%</th> <td align="left"><img height="100%" src="grnline.gif" width="32.977437%"></td></tr>
<tr><th colspan="6" align="center">Linux Nodes (z/VM-Guests)</th></tr> <tr><td/><td colspan="5"><table cols="3" width="100%" border="1px">
<tr><th width="50px"> <a href="http://jassadmin.nj.example.com/adminsvcs/jassgleprocess.jsp?search_criteria=jas1a419" target="_blank">jas1a419</a></th><th style="width:50px">121.58%</th> <td align="left"><img height="100%" src="redline.png" width="100%"></td></tr>
<tr><th width="50px"> <a href="http://jassadmin.nj.example.com/adminsvcs/jassgleprocess.jsp?search_criteria=jas1a443" target="_blank">jas1a443</a></th><th style="width:50px">45.07%</th> <td align="left"><img height="100%" src="grnline.gif" width="45.07199%"></td></tr>
<tr><th width="50px"> <a href="http://jassadmin.nj.example.com/adminsvcs/jassgleprocess.jsp?search_criteria=jas1a185" target="_blank">jas1a185</a></th><th style="width:50px">36.53%</th> <td align="left"><img height="100%" src="grnline.gif" width="36.52853%"></td></tr>
<tr><th width="50px"> <a href="http://jassadmin.nj.example.com/adminsvcs/jassgleprocess.jsp?search_criteria=jas1a435" target="_blank">jas1a435</a></th><th style="width:50px">23.19%</th> <td align="left"><img height="100%" src="grnline.gif" width="23.18803%"></td></tr>
</td></tr></table>
</table></body></html>


library(rvest)
q <- html(url1) %>% html_table(fill=T)
t2 <- as.data.frame(q[[2]][-3])
t1 <- as.data.frame(q[[1]])
```

it works but sometimes q does not have the second series only q[[1]] and my scripts is failing. Is there a way to put in a check to see if q[[2]] exists then do the assignment?

Comment: can you provide a URL? you can actually do a check at the XML/HTML level

Comment: @hrbrmstr, the url is an internal site but I just include the html data that url call returns. Does that help?

Comment: for this, you can probably test for `length(q)`. if you need to ensure that `q[[1]]` is the "first" list then you can probably use `ncol` on it.

Comment: I do this lenght(q[[2]]), I get this error: Error in q[[2]] : subscript out of bounds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well here is my solution, just a shortcut with `lapply`. The behavior of this function is:

> apply returns a list of the same length as X, each element of which is
>   the result of applying FUN to the corresponding element of X.

```
li <- list(NA, "string", 10, TRUE, NaN)
 lapply(li, is.na)
[[1]]
[1] TRUE

[[2]]
[1] FALSE

[[3]]
[1] FALSE

[[4]]
[1] FALSE

[[5]]
[1] TRUE
```

### Edit to comments:

As BlondedDust pointed out:

```
is.na(li)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Why not just `is.na(li)`?

Comment: @BondedDust because honestly I thought that passing a list as an `is.na` argument would have a result of length 1. I do knot know why I had this idea in my mind.